# Windows phone 7 consume from Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, windows-phone-7

I have been reading about adding a webservice to an MVC project and how this might conflict with the MVC structure. I added a webservice and it works with windows phone 7, it receives a number, (it's a simple application). I added the webservice by right clicking the Controller folder and selecting add new item->webservice. I am using the SOAP support already integrated in visual studio. I was wondering if there is a way that instead of adding a webservice that the windows phone 7 receives and sends data directly to the controller.
The windows phone  7 communicates by right clicking on the solution explorer and adding a service reference.

Thanks!

i also read [ASP.NET MVC & Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118931/asp-net-mvc-web-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to use the "Add Service Reference" in your WP7 project then you'll most likely need to expose a WCF Web Service from your project.

If you're prefer to create a simpler REST based as discussed in [ASP.NET MVC & Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118931/asp-net-mvc-web-services) then you won't be able to use "Add Service Reference" but you can still use the service either through building your own client on top of WebClient, there are few libraries to help with this. I recommend [Hammock](http://hammock.codeplex.com/).