# how access database in wcf service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making project in asp.net mvc3 and I have make a wcf webservice. I have to access database in wcf webservice. How i access controller class in wcf service method. 
if any other way to use then suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to you want to access the controller? That doesn't make any sense. Otherwise [ASP.NET MVC & Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118931/asp-net-mvc-web-services) might help.

Comment: then how i access database i have to retrive and insert value in database.

Comment: Just use the same model as for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of using `Web Service` you can use `Web API`. You can add web api by adding `Web API Controller` (`v2` is good) and then you will see many auto implemented methods are there like `get, post` etc.

You can implement your code in those method or can built your own method. also if you want to give your `custom url pattern` to your methods then also you can do it by providing `route config` above the method.

And you can use your `model classes` in this `webapi` directly, so that you can save data into database.